# How do you reduce an 8 output ALU to a 4 or 3 output ALU?

Tags: digital-logic, computers, computer-architecture, vlsi, alu

I can implement the functions in the picture below, but then if I implement them independently, I would have 8 outputs to the mux. Our professors wants us to reduce the ALU to only 3 or 4 outputs, I have tried but am not getting anywhere?

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on what you tried.

Comment: Hint: What's the difference between 6 and 7? Between 3 and 5? Between 4 and 5?

Comment: the difference btw 5 & 7 is that they are opposites, diff btw 3&5 is that one is subtraction and the other is anding. 4 and 5 are oring and anding, but i don't see how to use these differences. i can only use xnor and xor because they are opposites, but the rest i can't see

Comment: Have you learned about De Morgan yet?

Comment: i have about demorgan, and can become or but flipped. i quite can't see how to use it here

Comment: 4 & 5 are quite the same except that one is inverted. relating 3 and 5 in demorgan is quite confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition and subtraction have inverted constants \$C_{in}\$, we can be connected to \$(I_3 \vee I_4)\$. Then invert the subtracting value before passing to a full adder. ADD/SUBR/SUBS can be expressed as :

$$
(R \forall I_3) + (S \forall I_4) + (I_3 \vee I_4)
$$

Using the same xor inversion method you can mearge:
AND/NOTRS : \$ (R \forall I_3) \wedge S\$
EXOR/EXNOR : \$ R \forall S \forall I_3\$

This make 4 possibilities that can be decoded using three 2-to-1 muxes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOMZo9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Hint: Gate count can be reduced further by share logic with the gates inside the fulladder.*

Comment: thhankyou very much, this is very very helpful